# I'm always turning back

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> I voice my disagreement at the start
>   while holding all of time between my hands
>   so I can finally become aware
>   that I'm always turning back.

What am I?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I voice my disagreement at the start

> counter - to voice opposition

while holding all of time between my hands

> clock - holds time, well all the 12 hours and then resets, within its hands

so I can finally become aware

> wise - have become aware

that I'm always turning back.

> counterclockwise - turning in a backwards direction of rotation, than usually considered forward

Comment: That's a winner :]

Answer (score 2):

You could be an

> hourglass

because

> it starts full from one half from the start and the sands continues (to disagree) till the end only to turn back again. Time is accounted between its ends.

Comment: How does this explain the first line about 'voicing disagreement at the start'?

Comment: @Stiv I was thinking along the lines of the sands moving along a direction to be an “argument” against the other end.